# Creating inner shadows in UIView to replicate Neumorphic Style

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation

I have the task to implement neumorphic design styles in my UIKit application. I have successfully implemented the double outer shadows (dark and light), but I somehow, can't figure out how to implement the inner shadows inside the view. I've tried approaches like `CAGradientLayer` that goes from `.black` to `.clear` to `.white`, but it isn't looking the way it is supposed to. I've searched the internet for various solutions, but couldn't seem to find one appropriate one.

How should I create the inner shadows? What approach should I use? I am fine with a solution in either Swift or Objective-C.

[Current state of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnNG2.png)

[The state that I am trying to reach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek5BS.png)

A simplified version of the current state (for the outer shadows):

```
class DebossedView: UIView {

private var outerDarkShadow = CALayer()
private var outerLightShadow = CALayer()

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    outerDarkShadow = shadowLayer(color: UIColor.black, shadowOffset: 10, shadowRadius: 12)
    outerLightShadow = shadowLayer(color: UIColor.white, shadowOffset: -10, shadowRadius: 10)
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = 3
    layer.insertSublayer(outerDarkShadow, at: 0)
    layer.insertSublayer(outerLightShadow, at: 0)
}

private func shadowLayer(color: UIColor, shadowOffset: CGFloat, shadowRadius: CGFloat) -> CALayer {
    let shadowLayer = CALayer()
    shadowLayer.frame = bounds
    shadowLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    shadowLayer.cornerRadius = 16
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffset, height: shadowOffset)
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    return shadowLayer
}
}
```

[Neumorphism information](https://artofofiare.medium.com/neumorphism-the-right-way-a-2020-design-trend-386e6a09040a)

Comment: Does this look like a good starting point for you to work from? https://medium.com/@mail2sajalkaushik/swift-creating-custom-neumorphic-view-using-uikit-fe94c60aedc1

Comment: @DonMag It was indeed a great starting point. The point where I am now, was inspired by that topic. From here forward, it is unknown for me.

Comment: OK - you need to try and clarify what you're having trouble with. Are you unable to add an image? Are your gradients *not quite* how you want them? It's difficult to tell what's not right.

Comment: I am trying to create the inner shadows inside the circle.

Comment: Is this your goal then? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZexQW.png (or, at least, closer)?

Comment: I am in the same point as in the image. The goal that I am trying to reach is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek5BS.png

Comment: As you can see, there are there 2 inner shadows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "goal" image does not really match the examples in the link you posted for "Neumorphism informations" so not sure this will give you the exact results you want.

However, couple notes...

1. `draw()` is **definitely *not*** where you want to be creating and adding/inserting sublayers.
2. you can use a `CAGradientLayer` to get the "inner" appearance (based on your goal image)
3. you can add a `UIImageView` as a subview to hold the image.

So, here's an example `UIView` subclass:

```
class NeuView: UIView {
    
    public var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            imgView.image = image
        }
    }
    
    private let imgView = UIImageView()
    private let darkShadow = CALayer()
    private let lightShadow = CALayer()
    
    private let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() -> Void {

        // add sublayers
        self.layer.addSublayer(darkShadow)
        self.layer.addSublayer(lightShadow)
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

        darkShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
        darkShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
        darkShadow.shadowOpacity = 1
        darkShadow.shadowRadius = 10

        lightShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.9).cgColor
        lightShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -5, height: -5)
        lightShadow.shadowOpacity = 1
        lightShadow.shadowRadius = 10

        // 45-degree gradient layer
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        
        
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 3
        
        // very light gray background color
        let bkgColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
        darkShadow.backgroundColor = bkgColor.cgColor
        lightShadow.backgroundColor = bkgColor.cgColor
        
        // set gradient colors from
        //  slightly darker than background to
        //  slightly lighter than background
        let c1 = UIColor(white: 0.92, alpha: 1.0)
        let c2 = UIColor(white: 0.97, alpha: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.colors = [c1.cgColor, c2.cgColor]

        // image view properties
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //imgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        addSubview(imgView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // let's make the image view 60% of self
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor),
            imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // set all layers' frames to bounds
        darkShadow.frame = bounds
        lightShadow.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        
        // set all layers' cornerRadius to one-half height
        let cr = bounds.height * 0.5
        darkShadow.cornerRadius = cr
        lightShadow.cornerRadius = cr
        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = cr
        layer.cornerRadius = cr
        
    }
    
}
```

and an example view controller:

```
class NeuTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let neuView = NeuView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "neu01") else {
            print("Could not load image!")
            return
        }
        
        neuView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(neuView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            neuView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            neuView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -60.0),
            neuView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            neuView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: neuView.widthAnchor),
            
        ])

        // set the image
        neuView.image = img
        
    }
    
}
```

Using this image (transparent background):

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

By tweaking the colors, shadow properties, etc, this may give you your desired result.

---

**Edit**

Here is a modified version of the `NewView` class.

Instead of using a gradient layer, we add a `CAShapeLayer` with a "hole" cutout, and use that layer to cast the "inner shadow":

```
class NeuView: UIView {
    
    public var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            imgView.image = image
        }
    }
    
    private let imgView = UIImageView()
    
    // "outer" shadows
    private let darkShadow = CALayer()
    private let lightShadow = CALayer()
    
    // "inner" shadow
    private let innerShadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let innerShadowMaskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        // add sublayers
        self.layer.addSublayer(darkShadow)
        self.layer.addSublayer(lightShadow)
        self.layer.addSublayer(innerShadowLayer)
        
        darkShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
        darkShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
        darkShadow.shadowOpacity = 1
        darkShadow.shadowRadius = 10
        
        lightShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.9).cgColor
        lightShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -5, height: -5)
        lightShadow.shadowOpacity = 1
        lightShadow.shadowRadius = 10
        
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
        //layer.borderWidth = 3
        
        // very light gray background color
        let bkgColor = UIColor(red: 0.94, green: 0.95, blue: 0.99, alpha: 1.0) // UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
        darkShadow.backgroundColor = bkgColor.cgColor
        lightShadow.backgroundColor = bkgColor.cgColor // UIColor(white: 0.98, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        
        // image view properties
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //imgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        addSubview(imgView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // let's make the image view 60% of self
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor),
            imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // set dark and light shadow layers' frames to bounds
        darkShadow.frame = bounds
        lightShadow.frame = bounds
        
        // set self.layer and dark and light shadow layers' cornerRadius to one-half height
        let cr = bounds.height * 0.5
        darkShadow.cornerRadius = cr
        lightShadow.cornerRadius = cr
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cr
        
        // for the "inner" shadow,
        // rectangle path needs to be larger than
        //  bounds + shadow offset + shadow raidus
        // so the shadow doesn't "bleed" from all sides
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds.insetBy(dx: -40, dy: -40))

        // create a path for the "hole" in the layer
        let circularHolePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds)
        
        // this "cuts a hole" in the path
        path.append(circularHolePath)
        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        
        innerShadowLayer.path = path.cgPath
        innerShadowLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        
        // fillColor doesn't matter - just needs to be opaque
        innerShadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        // mask the layer, so we only "see through the hole"
        innerShadowMaskLayer.path = circularHolePath.cgPath
        innerShadowLayer.mask = innerShadowMaskLayer

        // adjust properties as desired
        innerShadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 15, height: 15)
        innerShadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        innerShadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5
        
        // setting .shadowOpacity to a very small value (such as 0.025)
        //  results in very light shadow
        // set .shadowOpacity to 1.0 to clearly see
        //  what the shadow is doing
        innerShadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.025

    }

}
```

Example view controller:

```
class NeuTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let neuView = NeuView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.94, green: 0.95, blue: 0.99, alpha: 1.0)
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "neu01") else {
            print("Could not load image!")
            return
        }
        
        neuView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(neuView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            neuView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            neuView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 125.0),
            neuView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: neuView.widthAnchor),
            neuView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // set the image
        neuView.image = img

    }
    
}
```

Results - the top instance has the "inner shadow" opacity set to `0.9` (to make it clearly visible)... the bottom instance is set to `0.025`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! This is a great and well-documented solution. But unfortunately, this isn't yet what I am trying to get. I have tried this solution before with a gradient, but it isn't what it is meant to be looking. Thank you again for your time, appreciate it!

Comment: @FlaviusDolha - Other than very slight color differences, I can't really tell what's different between my result and your "goal" image. Are you trying to get an "inner shadow" along these lines? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIFUc.png ... obviously, not as dark, but that's just to emphasize the shadow.

Comment: That's right! Thank you very much!

Comment: @FlaviusDolha - see the **Edit** to my answer for a modified `NeuView` using an "inner shadow".

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, you have to create an overlay containing the blurred shape, clipped to the shape.
With the clipping, the outside part of the blur will disappear, and you will just have the inner blur as a shadow.